# Usage of 'hadn't had' and meaning of this sentence

Tags: meaning-in-context, past-tense

I read a novel(or maybe it's a short story since it is very short) by Alan Titchmarsh called 'Rosie'. It was going well until I stuck at Chapter 4. It writes

> How she had managed to be up and out of the house before **him was a mystery**. Nick knew she **hadn't had** that much to drink, but it had affected her.

The question is, is *him was a mystery* gramatically correct?

And how do we use *hadn't had* correctly and its meaning in this context?

Comment: 1. "...before him..." is correct. See your dictionary for a definition of "before." 2. Read this [link](http://ell.stackexchange.com/q/13255/37009).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that you are misparsing this. *Him* is not the subject of the main clause *X was a mystery*; that subject is the entire free relative clause *How ... him*.

> <sup>*subject*</sup>[How she had managed to be up and out of the house before him]  <sup>*verb*</sup>[was]  <sup>*complement*</sup>[a mystery].

*Had[n't] had* is an ordinary past perfect construction, indicating that her drinking occurred before the time the author is currently talking about.